# Netbeans 8.x + hibernate + postgreSQL : No tables found in reverse engineering

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I use neatbeans with hibernate + postgreSQL.

In postgreSQL I have 1 table : "test" with 3 columns.

I created the hibernate.cfg.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Now I want to create the reverse engineering file for map my table, the problem is I haven't output (in table field).

In my libraries I have:

- Hibernate 4.3.x
- postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41
- JDK 8

With NetBeans, when I go to Service area I can connect to my database, and see my tables with his values.

Maybe an idea, when I created the hibernate.cfg, I chose my new Driver -> Add postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar and when I click on "find" Driver Class I have the error message: Driver class is missing. I don't know if that could be the problem.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You need to add the driver to your **project** libraries, so that hibernate can find it. is that a Maven project, a Gradle project or a "native" NetBreans project (Ant based)? Also: that driver version is outdated, you should use the  current one (42.2.5)

Comment: Recently I too got the same issue Any help would be appreciated